# Restrict paste (Ctrl-V) in Excel cell from VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I had a scenario to generate and validate excel cell value with date cell through VB.NET, everything works fine when I type a value in the cell, but when I do a copy paste in the cell any string value it accepts and never validates.

The problem: I want to restrict the paste (Ctrl-V) in the cell from VB.NET. How can I achieve that?

This is my code:

```
    worksheet.Range(DateRange).Validation.Delete()
    worksheet.Range(DateRange).Validation
        .Add(ValidationType.Date, ValidationAlertStyle.Stop, 
            ValidationOperator.Greater, dt, Nothing)
    worksheet.Range(DateRange).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    worksheet.Range(DateRange).Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
    worksheet.Range(DateRange).Validation.InputTitle = "Excel Validation"
    worksheet.Range(DateRange).Validation.ErrorTitle = "Error in Date"
```

Comment: What is the source of the copy ? If those are cells it might be that you remove the validation when you paste the date.

Comment: Hi Vash, source of the copy can be anything(string) other than date, that cell accepts that value which is not date. So I am thiking we should restrict that copy paste in that cell. Please give me some idea to how to do this with VB.NET.

Comment: @Ramesh. I'm pretty sure that the only way to restrict copying and pasting in Excel but still allow editing is to trap it through macros. As Luke showed below, you can write macros to do it. To get those macros into the workbook you can use [this tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303871) to help you write them via VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

this is something ive found

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Right click menu deactivated." & vbCrLf & _
"Cannot copy or ''drag & drop''.", 16, "For this workbook:"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

source: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=84495

Comment: Hi Luke , I think this is VB Macro code, I am using VB.Net, so I cant write these excel events through vb.net. Correct me if i am wrong.